# Installing vpn configuration profile along with other MDM profile iOS

Tags: ios, mdm

I need to install an VPN configuration profile, which may be changed without user intervention at a later point of time. The straight way is to have the VPN profile installed, and installing the MDM profile so that the configuration can be changed at later point of time.

However, my requirement is only pertain to the VPN configuration and do not want to manage the device completely, and want to co-exist with other MDM vendor's profile installed.

Is there any less privileged way to do this? The main requirement is, I should be able to change my VPN configuration profile, though there is another MDM profile from different vendor is installed in the iOS device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to upgrade profiles without a user interaction is through MDM right now.

I would love to see iOS device being managed by multiple MDM (Which would alleviate interoperability problem). However, Apple doesn't support this.